# Is every linear orthogonal operator surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

An orthogonal operator T on some subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear operator that preserves the dot product, i.e., $T(\vec{x}) \cdot T(\vec{y})=\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}$. Are they all surjective?

Comment: If $T:V\rightarrow W$ where $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have the same dimension, then if $T$ is not surjective, then $T$ has a nontrivial kernel.  Let $v$ be in the kernel of $T$.  Then $v\cdot v\geq 0$, but $T(v)\cdot T(v)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: When you restrict yourself to finite dimensional spaces, this is certainly true. An orthogonal operator is the same as an orthogonal matrix, these are always invertible, hence such a map is a bijection.

Comment: I think the first suggestion is proving that T is injective right?

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $ T: V \rightarrow V$ an isometry. $T$ is clearly injective: if $T(x)=0$, then $||x||=||T(x)||=0$ implies $x=0$. This shows that $T$'s kernel is trivial.

For the dimension formula,

$$\dim \text{ker}(T)+\dim \text{im}(T)= \dim (V) \implies \dim \text{im}(T)=\dim(V)$$

so the map is surjective.